# How to store a SQL Server query result to Powershell Array?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting and currently working on a script to load the result of SQL Server query to store as a PowerShell array. Below is my code for reference. :

```
 $SQLServer = 'MyServer';
 $Database = 'Test';
    
 ## - Connect to SQL Server using non-SMO class 'System.Data':
 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
 $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = `
 "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True";
    
 $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
 $SqlCmd.CommandText = $("select distinct Servername from dbo.tableA
where Servername like '%hw%'");
 $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;
 $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    
 ## - Extract and build the SQL data object '$DataSetTable':
 $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
 $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
 $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
    
 $SqlConnection.Close()
 $Servername = @[SqlAdapter]
```

I expect $Servername to be an array having data elements store as "Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3', etc. based on the sqlquery result. I am planning to utilize $Servername array to loop through each server in future. For now, I am able to successfully connect to database, but I am still not able to get the query result to store in a PowerShell array. Can someone please guide on where I am making mistake?

Comment: from MS doc,  Fill(DataSet)  Adds or refreshes rows in the DataSet. (Inherited from DbDataAdapter), e.g. populate empty array, $colArry, with data from $DataSet.    $colArry=@() $data = $DataSet.Tables[0]  foreach ($colval in $data.Rows) {$colArry += $colval[1] $colArry += $colval[2] }. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try using following to see you dataset : $DataSet | Format-Table

Answer (score 1):

> `$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)`

This fills the [`[System.Data.DataSet]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataSet) instance stored in `$DataSet` with the query results, which is why you must use `$DataSet` to get the data you need (untested):

```
$serverNames = $DataSet.Tables[0].Server
```

- `.Tables[0]` accesses the first and only [`[System.Data.DataTable]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable) instance in the dataset containing the query results.
- `.Server` retrieves the the values of the query result's `Server` column, courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).

  - Note that this means that if there's only *one* result row, `$serverNames` will contain a *single string* rather than a single-element *array* containing that string.
  - To ensure that an array is *always* returned, use 
    `$serverNames = @($DataSet.Tables[0].Server)`, or, with a (strong) type constraint, 
    `[string[]] $serverNames = $DataSet.Tables[0].Server`

---

As for **what you tried**:

- PowerShell statements only ever need to be separated with `;` if they're placed *on the same line*, which means that all the `;` instances in your code are unnecessary.
- While `$("select distinct Servername from dbo.tableA where Servername like '%hw%'")` technically works, there is no reason to wrap a double-quoted string literal (`"..."`) in the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) - just omit the `$(...)` enclosure.
- As for `$Servername = @[SqlAdapter]`: perhaps that was just pseudo code, but, to be clear: `@[...]` isn't a valid syntax construct in PowerShell (at least as of PowerShell 7.3<sup>[1]</sup>).

---

<sup>[1] By curious coincidence, `@[...]` just came up as potential *future* syntax for simplifying PowerShell's `[pscustomobject]` object-literal syntax - see [GitHub issue #18747](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18747#issuecomment-1344728601).</sup>